# Can this Expression be simplified

Tags: javascript, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I need to simplify this expression

```
  var foo = (!A && B && C) || (A && B && !C) ;
```

Can anyone suggest a good simplification using minimal operators ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`B` is common in both condition, for rest conditional operator can be used.

```
var foo = B && (A ? !C : C);
```

Its an XOR operation, do read [Logical XOR in JavaScript](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/xor.html)

Comment: Cool. Good use of Conditional.

Comment: I just spent 5 minutes thinking of the different combinations, this is what I think is the best in terms of readability and simpleness.

Comment: @Satpal Thanks. I think this is the best possible simplification.

Answer (score 2):

Since `(!A && C) || (A && !C)` is the expansion of XOR, you can replace that part with an XOR expression:

```
var foo = B && (!!A ^ !!C);
```

Comment: The double exclamation marks `!!` have no point and should be removed.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin They very much have a point. `!!4 ^ !!8` is `0` (falsy), but `4 ^ 8` is `12` (truthy). `!!"nonempty" ^ !!""` is `1` (truthy), but `"nonempty" ^ ""` is `0` (falsy).